# Xcode 4 -- how to find the built project's binary

Tags: find, xcode4

I need a tool for my development work. This tool only exists in code form. So I have to build it. I'm following the instructions in http://projects.akosma.com/projects/nib2objc/wiki/Build_Instructions.

Everything looks good. I press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Xcode 4). Everything successfully builds, but nothing runs. Unsurprising, it is a commandline tool. But how do I find the binary that just got generated?

Also, what happened to debug / release build? I bet I am running a debug build, but I can't find how to toggle it.

Comment: The link seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand the Products group, right click on your tool's name and click 'Reveal in Finder'.